# Type constraint mismatch when using List.sum

Tags: compiler-errors, f#

I may have been away from F# for too long, but I would have expected this to compile:

```
module Calc

let foo values = List.sum values
```

Instead, I get a compilation error:

> ```
> FS0071 Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type 'obj' for a type
> inference variable. The type 'obj' does not support the operator '+' Consider
> adding further type constraints
> ```

This also happens for `List.average`, so at first I thought it had something to do with generic constraints like *requires member ( + ) and member get_Zero*, but that can't be the whole story, since `let foo values = List.max values` compiles (`List.max` also has a generic constraint, albeit a simpler one - it only requires comparison).

What am I doing wrong?

This is a .NET 5.0 project. Compilation fails both in Visual Studio and with `dotnet build`.

Comment: `List.max` requires `comparison` and it can be easily generalized. `List.sum` & `List.average` requires SRTP, so this is harder to generalize. I used `let inline foo values = List.sum values` and it compiles

Comment: Consider that `List.max` can operate on a list of strings or a list of dates, but `List.sum` cannot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List.sum` has an SRTP type with a requirement that the element of the list has a `(+)` operator defined on it:

```
val sum:
   list: list< ^T>
      -> ^T (requires static member ( + ) and static member Zero )
```

When you try to call that without knowing the type of the list element, the compiler can't resolve the SRTP.

---

**One option** would be to mark `foo` itself `inline`:

```
let inline foo values = List.sum values
```

That way, `foo` itself will inherit the SRTP requirement:

```
val foo:
   values: list< ^a>
        -> ^a (requires static member ( + ) and static member Zero )
```

And you're just kicking the problem down the line - presumably to the point where you know the type of the element.

This doesn't work without an `inline` modifier, because SRTPs can't be compiled to IL.

---

**Another option**, if you can afford it, is to specify an element type, such that it has a `(+)` operator:

```
let foo (values: int list) = List.sum values
```

This way the compiler can resolve SRTP right there by observing that `int` does indeed have a `(+)` operator.

---

This works fine with `List.max`, because `max` doesn't have an SRTP constraint on it. It only has an `'T :> IComparison` constraint, which are supported by the IL, so they don't have to be SRTP.

Comment: Ah, yes, I'd forgotten about `inline`. As I wrote, I've been away for too long  Thank you.

Comment: Can you define SRTP or link to an explanation?

Comment: Sure thing. Here's literally the first link I found by searching "f# srtp": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters